Configuring small network for RDP over long distance (100 meters)
I have to make a small network for connecting two laptops over Windows Remote Desktop. Here is the situation: In a venue, there are two screens. Both of them must be showing the same thing during an event. But the problem is, there screens are 100 meters away from each other. I contacted some subcontractors for these issue. They told me I can do this with only one laptop over HDMI to Fiber optic cable. But they told me a very high price for HDMI over fiber optic converters. So I have to figure out another way. The main thing here is to synchronize the screens of two laptops. Each connected to one of the screens. So I think if I would be able to connect these laptops over RDP I could get the nearly same result.
The thing is, I don't know how to do these because I have no knowledge of netword equipment. But I tried this concept over TightVNC over local WIFI network yesterday and it worked. Can someone show me the way to do this for 100 meters?
I think there should be a way of connecting two laptops each other with ethernet cable. But I am not sure if this can support 100 meters length.
Question 1: Is it possible to construct this network withhout any equimpent in between two PCs.
Question 2: If not, would my home router be enough for transmitting information over CAT5 UTP cable to 100 meters.
Question 3: Which problem would I face If I construct this network? (Other than  distance)
I am in no place to buy additional network equipment for this issue except cables. So I think I should figure out doing this with a router I use at home for connection.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

100 meters is generally the certified maximum distance for the most common twisted-pair Ethernet standards up to 1 Gbps (and with good-quality cable you should be able to go a bit beyond that), so I'm tempted to say that it should just Work as-is: get a suitable Ethernet cable and configure the laptops.
But the limit is only for the physical link, not for the data link. If you place an Ethernet switch in the middle, then each of the two cables (PC1-switch and switch-PC2) has its own separate ~100 m limit, as the switch terminates the signal and generates its own – that should easily give you ~200 meters without any extra configuration.
This should also apply to home routers which all have a built-in switch for their 'LAN' ports; each physical connection has its own distance limit port-to-port, but the complete Ethernet link does not, so placing a regular wireless router somewhere in the ~middle may work.
(There also exist "Ethernet amplifiers", small in-line PoE-powered devices that can extend the distance to ~200 meters in a similar way, but those might be harder to obtain than a generic cheap switch.)
For longer distances, or in case of interference, you can also buy switches with fiber SFP modules, as well as standalone Ethernet "media converters" that accept twisted-pair Ethernet on one side and fiber Ethernet on the other. Unlike the HDMI ones, 1 Gbps fiber Ethernet equipment tends to be really cheap.
I'm a lot less sure about the RDP/VNC part; it feels like an RTP stream (like network cameras use) might provide better latency.

Thank you for your answer. I am planning to use RDP/VNC because I must be able to control the presentation from both PCs.
